# Link Excel cells without using an IF formula

Tags: excel

I've made an action tracker that consolidates lots of different meetings in different tabs.

For example, daily catch-ups are tab A and weekly prioritisation meetings are tab B - all of the actions from daily catch-ups go into the table in tab A, all of the actions from the weekly prioritisation meetings go into the table in tab B.
There is also ANOTHER tab called "All Actions" which is a much longer table with all of the actions from ALL of the meetings so it's easy to see how many open actions you have across the meetings at one time. Each action has its own unique reference number and a status cell which can only say "open" or "closed" and these are in both tables.

I want to link the status cells in both tables so that if I change the status from "open" to "closed" in the All Actions table, the status cell in the meeting table will also change from open to closed. This would be an easy IF formula
BUTTTTTT
I need it to do the same the other way around as well - so if I change the status in the meeting table it changes in the All Actions table.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Definitely possible with VBA.

Comment: ^^ In fact, I think it's only possible through VBA.